# Force localStorage event to fire in a different window

Tags: html, jquery, event-handling, local-storage, jquery-events

When the user clicks on a link it opens a page, adds some content to the local storage then the page that was just opened is supposed to listen for `localStorage` events. It doesn't seem to fire as I understand both windows must be opened at the same time for the storage event to fire. So I tried to invoke it manually like this:

```
//page containing the link to other window

$('.view-btn').click(function () {
            var selectionName = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first').text();
            var key = "sel-view-1";
            addToStorage(key, selectionName);          
});



var addToStorage = function (key, value) {
                defineKey(key, value);
    
                var e = $.Event("storage");
                e.originalEvent = {
                    key: key,
                    newValue: value
                };
                var windowRef = window.open("Create_a_selection", "_self");
                $(windowRef).trigger(e);
            };

var defineKey = function (key, value) {
            if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null) {
                localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            } else {
                var nr = parseInt(key.substring(key.lastIndexOf('-') + 1)) + 1;
                key = 'sel-view-' + nr;
                return defineKey(key, value);
            }
        }
```

---

```
//page that was just opened

$(window).bind('storage', onStorageEvent);
            
        function onStorageEvent(storageEvent) {
            console.log('yay');
            if (storageEvent.originalEvent) {
                var key = storageEvent.originalEvent.key;
                var value = storageEvent.originalEvent.newValue;
                if (key.indexOf("sel-view") > -1) {
                    $('#selection-name-label').html(value);
                }
            }
        };
```

But this still doesn't catch the event... It does however catch it if the page is already opened so I'm wondering if this could have something to do with the page not being loaded yet perhaps?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it has to do with the page not loading yet, you could put it in document.ready  `$(function(){ /*code here*/ });`.  I don't know if that is the issue or not though.

Comment: @GaryStorey tried, doesn't seem to be the problem :/